# RPI4 Camara module v1 - Slow FPS in python script

Tags: python, pi-4, raspicam

I'm doing a project that needs a python script to capture and process an image at 3-5 FPS. I'm doing some initial tests and my Camera Module v1 can only capture at 0.85 FPS @ 320 * 240 (also tested at 160 * 128, no difference) in the script.

I need to capture the image as a numpy array.

The code I'm using to capture frames is:

```
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (320, 240)
camera.framerate = 5
time.sleep(2)

def getFrame():
    output = np.empty((240, 320, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    camera.capture(output, 'rgb')
    return output
```

Full test script: https://gist.github.com/thezaza101/1ab772d32ad4d5240482e9a8db647816

Any idea on how to speed this up?

I'm using an RPI4 4GB model

Answer (score 0):

I believe the better way to capture a series of frames is so use the `capture_sequence()` method. Please see this link for context: [picamera docs](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/recipes2.html#rapid-capture-and-processing)

This snippet should help:

```
import time
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
    camera.framerate = 30
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(2)
    camera.capture_sequence([
        'image1.jpg',
        'image2.jpg',
        'image3.jpg',
        'image4.jpg',
        'image5.jpg',
        ])
```